# Get random number of colors from a list instead of 8

Tags: javascript, random

I am experimenting on particles and I have set a list of 8 colors that create random shape. Now I have always the 8 colors showing up in the particles but I would like to have a random number of colors (1 to 8) everytime I run the script.

this is the relevant part of the code:

```
let colors = [
   "dodgerBlue",
  "red",
  "#fff200",
  "limeGreen",
  "slateGrey",
  "orange",
  "hotPink", 
  " #080808"
];
const dpi = 100;

let Particle = function(x, y) {
  this.x =  getRandomInt(cw);
  this.y =  getRandomInt(ch);
  this.coord = {x:x, y:y};
  this.r =  Math.min(getRandomInt(cw / dpi), 10 );
  this.vx = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 100;
  this.vy = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 100;
  this.accX = 0;
  this.accY = 0;
  this.friction = Math.random() * 0.07 + 0.90;
  this.color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 8)];
}
```

how can I get a random number output instead of the "8" of the last line?

Comment: Trim your color list before the generation of particles

Comment: You can use simply `this.coord = {x, y};` instead of `this.coord = {x:x, y:y};`. if you want to define an object whose keys have the same name as the variables passed in as properties, you can use the shorthand and simply pass the key name.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do three things:

**Shuffle the array**

I'll just use the shuffle code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6274381/16584778):

```js
/**
 * Shuffles array in place.
 * @param {Array} a items An array containing the items.
 */
function shuffle(a) {
    var j, x, i;
    for (i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        x = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = x;
    }
    return a;
}
```

**Remove items from the array**

Easiest way to do this is with the slice function. You just do `array.slice(0, 3)` and that would keep the first few items. In your example you would want to randomise the second number, ensuring it's always 1 or more.

**No hard-coding the array length**

In your code there's an 8 for the length of the array. That could be improved by using the `array.length` because that will handle any length and it's easier to understand.

**Example**

Putting that together would give:

```js
/**
 * Shuffles array in place. ES6 version
 * @param {Array} a items An array containing the items.
 * https://stackoverflow.com/a/6274381/16584778
 */
function shuffle(a) {
    for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
    }
    return a;
}

var colours = [
  "red",
  "green",
  "blue",
  "yellow",
  "black",
  "pink",
  "orange",
  "purple"
];

// randomise the order of the colours
shuffle(colours);

// keep some/all of the colours
colours = colours.slice(0, 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length));

// show the colours that we have kept
document.write(colours.join(' ') + '<br/>');

// output dots using our chosen colours
for (var n = 0; n < 200; n++) {
  document.write('<span style="color:' + colours[Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length)] + '">&#9632;</span> ');
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I already have the output of particles. 
I also tried to embed the code but I get only one-color particles output (as when I run the snippet). Any hint?

Comment: That's weird - you get only one colour every time you run the snippet? Is it always the same colour?

Comment: can't post a picture but yes, only one color (blue) and always the same color

Comment: How about now ?

Answer (score 1):

`Math.floor()`     returns max less or equal number,that why u allways have the same 8.
Specify youre requirments and use this insted youre last line:

```
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
 }
```

That function will return allways random value in specifyed diapason.

Comment: That sounds easy and straightforward. I tried implementing the code but I always get black particles. Can you help me get that piece of code working with minimum 1 color and maximum 8 colors? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```js
Array.prototype.random = function(){
  return this[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length)];
}

let colors = [
   "dodgerBlue",
  "red",
  "#fff200",
  "limeGreen",
  "slateGrey",
  "orange",
  "hotPink", 
  " #080808"
];

// syntax use 

console.log(colors.random())
```

Comment: This does indeed provide a random color but not like op asked, op asked to get 1-8 random colors so some times it gives 1 random color, some times 3, some times 7 etc.